# Why can't I index with Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have run `rake ts:config` to generate the config file for Sphinx.

But, when I try to run `rake ts:index` to create an index I get a bunch of these errors:

```
indexing index 'activity_core'...
ERROR: source 'activity_core_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.
ERROR: index 'activity_core': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
```

I have mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for osx10.9 (x86_64) installed and running.

When I run `which indexer` it returns `/usr/local/bin/indexer`

I apologize if I'm misinformed. I do not have much experience with Sphinx or indexing. If you need more information leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your version of Sphinx was compiled without MySQL support. How did you install Sphinx? And did you install Sphinx *before* MySQL? Either way, it's worth re-installing Sphinx.

For those using Homebrew on OS X, this is done like so:

```
brew install sphinx --mysql
```

It's also worth noting that Thinking Sphinx requires Sphinx to be compiled with MySQL support, even when you're using PostgreSQL for your database (as the MySQL protocol is used to communicate with the Sphinx daemon).

Comment: You were right. I uninstalled Sphinx and reinstalled it with `brew install sphinx --mysql` and that did the trick. You can update your answer with this if you'd like. Thanks

Comment: it should be brew install sphinx --with-mysql

Comment: Key point on "uninstalling and reinstalling with `--with-mysql` flag" for OSX + MAMP users